# ¿Como puedo alinear los botones forma horizontal en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Hola quisiera saber como puedo ordenar los botones de forma horizontal para la siguiente ventana. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MatrizGrafica extends JPanel {

    private JTable tabla;

    public MatrizGrafica() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        tabla = new JTable(new MiTablaModelo());
        tabla.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(900, 200));
        tabla.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        add(new JScrollPane(tabla));

    }

    static class MiTablaModelo extends AbstractTableModel {
//private String [] dias = {"Nombres","Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"};

        private String[] dias = {"Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"};
        private String[] nombres = {"Pedro Hernández", "Juan Cardona", "Ana Magaña", "Carlos Soriano", "Roberto Durán", "María López", "Luisa Tobar", "Jorge Escalante", "Roxana Flores", "Rosa Cea"};

//Object [][] datos = {
//{"Pedro Hernández", 123.65, 113.23, 143.23, 131.34, 153.32, 195.34, 125.98},
//{"Juan Cardona",139.56, 139.39, 131.98, 183.47, 162.27, 150.06, 191.84},
//{"Ana Magaña",169.61, 191.91, 119.87, 132.71, 125.21, 107.61, 119.43},
//{"Carlos Soriano", 169.16, 129.29, 151.88, 133.77, 192.27, 160.76, 181.34},
//{"Roberto Durán",159.66, 179.89, 131.98, 198.47, 162.74, 110.55, 153.65},
//{"María López",132.89, 139.76, 183.84, 136.31, 140.46, 171.62, 118.23},
//{"Luisa Tobar",134.46, 145.23, 175.38, 153.73, 184.28, 179.42, 153.07},
//{"Jorge Escalante",172.32, 149.72, 157.61, 128.61, 167.72, 137.71, 174.52},
//{"Roxana Flores", 129.34, 148.63, 193.38, 138.28, 120.52, 154.16, 162.18},
//{"Rosa Cea",137.84, 174.58, 173.73, 117.37, 193.25, 137.15, 127.41}
//};
        Object[][] datos = {
            {123.65, 113.23, 143.23, 131.34, 153.32, 195.34, 125.98},
            {139.56, 139.39, 131.98, 183.47, 162.27, 150.06, 191.84},
            {169.61, 191.91, 119.87, 132.71, 125.21, 107.61, 119.43},
            {169.16, 129.29, 151.88, 133.77, 192.27, 160.76, 181.34},
            {159.66, 179.89, 131.98, 198.47, 162.74, 110.55, 153.65},
            {132.89, 139.76, 183.84, 136.31, 140.46, 171.62, 118.23},
            {134.46, 145.23, 175.38, 153.73, 184.28, 179.42, 153.07},
            {172.32, 149.72, 157.61, 128.61, 167.72, 137.71, 174.52},
            {129.34, 148.63, 193.38, 138.28, 120.52, 154.16, 162.18},
            {137.84, 174.58, 173.73, 117.37, 193.25, 137.15, 127.41}
        };

//tomo el numero de columnas
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return dias.length;
        }

// tomo el numero de filas 
        public int getRowCount() {
            return nombres.length;
        }

// nombre de las columnas
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return dias[col];
        }

//nombre de las filas 
        public String getRowName(int fil) {
            return nombres[fil];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int fil, int col) {
            return datos[fil][col];

        }

    }

    static class Action1 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MiTablaModelo modelo = new MiTablaModelo();
            double total = 0.0, prom = 0.0;
            String[] dias = modelo.dias;
            String[] vendedores = modelo.nombres;
            double vMenor = (double) modelo.getValueAt(0, 0);
            int fila = 0, columna = 0, i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < modelo.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    if (vMenor > (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j)) {
                        vMenor = (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j);
                        fila = i;
                        columna = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                total += (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, columna);
            }
            prom = total / dias.length;

            DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

            String mensaje = "Venta menor = " + vMenor + "\nDía de la venta = " + dias[columna] + "\nVendedor = "
                    + vendedores[fila] + "\nPromedio de ventas = " + formato.format(prom);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Datos de la venta menor",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    static class Action2 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MiTablaModelo modelo = new MiTablaModelo();
            double total = 0.0, prom = 0.0;
            String[] dias = modelo.dias;
            String[] vendedores = modelo.nombres;
            double vMayor = (double) modelo.getValueAt(0, 0);
            int fila = 0, columna = 0, i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < modelo.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    if (vMayor < (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j)) {
                        vMayor = (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j);
                        fila = i;
                        columna = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                total += (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, columna);
            }
            prom = total / dias.length;

            DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

            String mensaje = "Venta mayor = " + vMayor + "\nDía de la venta = " + dias[columna] + "\nVendedor = "
                    + vendedores[fila] + "\nPromedio de ventas = " + formato.format(prom);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Datos de la venta mayor",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    static class Action3 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MiTablaModelo modelo = new MiTablaModelo();
            double total = 0.0, prom = 0.0;
            int i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < modelo.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    total += (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j);
                }
            }

            prom = total / (modelo.getRowCount() * modelo.getColumnCount());

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

            String mensaje = "Promedio general = " + df.format(prom);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Promedio general de ventas",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

    }

    static class Action4 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MiTablaModelo modelo = new MiTablaModelo();
            double total = 0.0, prom = 0.0;
            String[] dias = modelo.dias;
            String[] vendedores = modelo.nombres;
            double ventasV = (double) modelo.getValueAt(0, 0);
            int fila = 0, columna = 0, i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {

                for (j = 0; j < modelo.getColumnCount(); j++) {

//fila = i ;
//columna = j ;
//}
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i++ < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {

            }
            for (i = 0; i++ < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                total += (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, columna);
                prom = total;
                DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
                String mensaje = "\nVendedor = " + vendedores[fila] + " Ventas Por Semana = " + formato.format(prom);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Datos de Venta por Vendedor",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }

        }
    }

    static class Action5 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MiTablaModelo modelo = new MiTablaModelo();
            double total = 0.0, prom = 0.0;
            String[] dias = modelo.dias;
            String[] vendedores = modelo.nombres;
            double pMenor = (double) modelo.getValueAt(0, 0);
            int fila = 0, columna = 0, i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < modelo.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    if (pMenor > (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j)) {
                        pMenor = (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j);
                        fila = i;
                        columna = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                total += (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, columna);
            }
            prom = total / dias.length;

            DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

            String mensaje = "\nPromedio de ventas = " + formato.format(prom) + "\nDía de la venta = " + dias[columna] + "\nVendedor = "
                    + vendedores[fila];

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Datos de Promedio menor",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    static class Action6 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MiTablaModelo modelo = new MiTablaModelo();
            double total = 0.0, prom = 0.0;
            String[] dias = modelo.dias;
            String[] vendedores = modelo.nombres;
            double pMayor = (double) modelo.getValueAt(0, 0);
            int fila = 0, columna = 0, i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < modelo.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    if (pMayor > (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j)) {
                        pMayor = (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, j);
                        fila = i;
                        columna = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                total += (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, columna);
            }
            prom = total / dias.length;

            DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

            String mensaje = "\nPromedio de ventas = " + formato.format(prom) + "\nDía de la venta = " + dias[columna] + "\nVendedor = "
                    + vendedores[fila];

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Datos de Promedio Mayor",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    static class Action7 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MiTablaModelo modelo = new MiTablaModelo();
            double total = 0.0, prom = 0.0;
            String[] dias = modelo.dias;
            String[] vendedores = modelo.nombres;
            double promedioD = (double) modelo.getValueAt(0, 0);
            int fila = 0, columna = 0, i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {

                for (j = 0; j < modelo.getColumnCount(); j++) {

                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i++ < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {

            }
            for (i = 0; i++ < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                total += (double) modelo.getValueAt(i, columna);
                prom = total;
                DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
                String mensaje = "\nDia = " + dias[fila] + " Promedio Diario = " + formato.format(prom);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje, "Promedio por Dias",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }

        }
    }

    private static void crearYMostrarGUI() {
        JFrame marco = new JFrame("Tabla semanal de ventas");
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MatrizGrafica panel = new MatrizGrafica();
        marco.setContentPane(panel);

        JButton mostrarVMenor = new JButton("Venta menor");
        marco.add(mostrarVMenor);
        mostrarVMenor.addActionListener(new Action1());

        JButton mostrarVMayor = new JButton("Venta mayor");
        marco.add(mostrarVMayor);
        mostrarVMayor.addActionListener(new Action2());

// Botón para mostrar el promedio general de ventas
        JButton mostrarProm = new JButton("Promedio total");
        marco.add(mostrarProm);
        mostrarProm.addActionListener(new Action3());

        JButton mostrarventasV = new JButton("Ventas X Vendedor");
        marco.add(mostrarventasV);
        mostrarventasV.addActionListener(new Action4());

        JButton mostrarpMenor = new JButton("Promedio Menor");
        marco.add(mostrarpMenor);
        mostrarpMenor.addActionListener(new Action5());

        JButton mostrarpMayor = new JButton("Promedio Mayor");
        marco.add(mostrarpMayor);
        mostrarpMayor.addActionListener(new Action6());

        JButton mostrarpromedioD = new JButton("Promedio por Dias");
        marco.add(mostrarpromedioD);
        mostrarpromedioD.addActionListener(new Action7());

        marco.pack();
        marco.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        marco.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                crearYMostrarGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues viendo tu código, lo mejor es crear 2 paneles. Uno para la tabla, y otro para los botones.
Agregamos el panel de la Tabla en la zona Norte, y el panel de los botones en la zona Sur.

**Norte - Tabla**

```
MatrizGrafica panel = new MatrizGrafica();
marco.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

**Sur - Botones**

```
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
marco.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

---

Te dejo el código del método que crea la interfaz gráfica.

```
private static void crearYMostrarGUI() {
        JFrame marco = new JFrame("Tabla semanal de ventas");
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MatrizGrafica panel = new MatrizGrafica();
        marco.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JButton mostrarVMenor = new JButton("Venta menor");
        panel2.add(mostrarVMenor);
        mostrarVMenor.addActionListener(new Action1());

        JButton mostrarVMayor = new JButton("Venta mayor");
        panel2.add(mostrarVMayor);
        mostrarVMayor.addActionListener(new Action2());

// Botón para mostrar el promedio general de ventas
        JButton mostrarProm = new JButton("Promedio total");
        panel2.add(mostrarProm);
        mostrarProm.addActionListener(new Action3());

        JButton mostrarventasV = new JButton("Ventas X Vendedor");
        panel2.add(mostrarventasV);
        mostrarventasV.addActionListener(new Action4());

        JButton mostrarpMenor = new JButton("Promedio Menor");
        panel2.add(mostrarpMenor);
        mostrarpMenor.addActionListener(new Action5());

        JButton mostrarpMayor = new JButton("Promedio Mayor");
        panel2.add(mostrarpMayor);
        mostrarpMayor.addActionListener(new Action6());

        JButton mostrarpromedioD = new JButton("Promedio por Dias");
        panel2.add(mostrarpromedioD);
        mostrarpromedioD.addActionListener(new Action7());

        marco.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        marco.pack();
        marco.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        marco.setVisible(true);

    }
```

---

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego, resolviste mi duda.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un layout para ordenar los componentes.

En este enlace puedes ver los ejemplos de layout que tienes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 0):

Para alinear tus botones podrías utilizar FlowLayout, ésta clase pone los componenete en una fila. Si el espacio horizontal es muy pequeño entonces usa varias filas.

Para utilizarlo se hace una instancia del objeto:

```
FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
```

...

```
final JPanel compsToExperiment = new JPanel();
 compsToExperiment.setLayout (experimentLayout);

compsToExperiment.add (new JButton ("Botón 1"));
    compsToExperiment.add (new JButton ("Botón 2"));
    compsToExperiment.add (new JButton ("Botón 3"));

//Seleccionar la orientación Izquierda-> Derecha
 compsToExperiment.setComponentOrientation(
                ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
```

Para invocarlos harás un una instancia en el main hacia la clase donde este escrito el FlowLaoyut.

Para más información te dejo estos enlaces:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/FlowLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/FlowLayoutDemo.java